# $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ piecewise defined

Tags: derivatives

my function is defined as follows:
$\frac{1}{x} $if $x \not = 0$, $ 1 $ if $ x=0$. Does the $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ in $x=0$ exist?

Answer (score 3):

No. Differentiability at a point implies continuity there. Since $f$ is not continuous at $0$, it can't be differentiable at $0$.